# Call a view controller programatically using storyboard id iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

### What I Want?

- In `MainViewController` I open a view from a xib programmatically. This
  xib view contains a `UIButton`. The xib opens successfully.
- On click of that `UIButton` I want to move `FeedBackViewController`

### My code

- This is the code I am using to move `FeedBackViewController` on click of the `UIButton`

  ```
  FeedBackViewController *view=[self.storyboad instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FeedBackView"];
  [self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
  ```

But it is crashing and I am receiving the following message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidARgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target FutureOrderViewController: 0x199a4a30.

Comment: are you sure are you used the XIB or storyboard for your VC

Comment: FeedBackViewController is in story board?

Answer (score 5):

Check these things

Check the identifier of the viewcontroller, if it is the same that you mentioned in storyboard

[image]

Make sure that your view object is not nil. Set a breakpoint on that line and on the debug area at the bottom see whether the object is not nil. If it is nil then problem lies in the storyboard connection

If your current viewcontroller is not launched from storyboard then get storyboard object like this :

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController * feedbackVC = [storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FeedBackView"] ;
[self presentViewController:feedbackVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

whenever you want to load a VC as the way you mentioned, you need two things.

**Thing 1:** Specific storyboard ID. you will find this by:

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Your_Storyboard_Id" bundle:nil];

In my case this is **Main**
[image]

**Thing 2:**

You need your View Controller id. Just click on the View Controller you want to go from storyboard and give a suitableName there.

[image]

Then invoke this like:

```
UIViewController * yourVC = [storyboard   
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourVC_ID"] ;
```

And if you want to present it modally you already did this. :)

```
[self presentViewController:yourVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
FeedBackViewController * feedbackVC = [story   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FeedBackView"] ;
[self presentViewController:feedbackVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Where **FeedBackView** is your storyboard id of FeedBackViewController.